# Position and extract table from pdf file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, text, pdf-parsing

Say I have many Chinese pdf files as follows:

[image]

In some pages of the files, they contain tables with same template as above.

So I want to position and extract those tables, then read as dataframe, or maybe merge them together and save as an excel file.

Just wondering if it's possible to do that in Python packages? I tried with `pdfminer`, `tika`, `tabula`, etc, but out of luck.

Since the PDF format has no internal representation of a table structure, which makes it difficult to extract tables for analysis. So I think maybe it's necessary to convert those files into images then use image recognition at this case.

Reference:

https://excalibur-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/